# Does elasticsearch ensures _id field is unique when we do not explicitly add that while inserting a document

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a few elastic search indexes in which i need to keep the _id field unique across all of them as i need to use the same for reference in others index documents, if i do not explicitly defines _id field does it ensures uniqueness across all indexes , something similar to mongodb _id field which is unique across all collection(mongodb does this by using timestamp concept)
for EX - when i created a elastic search document and did not defined _id explicitly i got the data in _id field 
like

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "app",
        "_type": "app",
        "_id": "8kznyGIBd_HxFbiV_E89",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "appfield": "5dc0f6ea00b2665a682f865b",
          "secretfield": "6a7d75798d1fc93107381d6f"


        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the auto generated Id field is a guide, so it will be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its unique for Elasticsearch 6.x and above. 
For previous version < 6.x. it was _uid (combination of _type and _id)

[Es official link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html)